# Why does my surface in the rendered preview look different from the real render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I created a surface and I'm using a material that looks like this in the render preview:

[image: Render preview]

But when I start a render I see this:

[image: Final render]

I don't understand why the surface is brown. I tried enabling the Transparent option in Render Settings, but then I can't see the surface at all.
Here's my file, but without textures, I don't know how to attach them.[image]

Comment: maybe you have a plane that is disabled in preview but enabled in render?

Comment: @moonboots no, in the first screen my surface is selected, and you can see that it's enabled in preview and in render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 hours spend I find out the reason. In particle settings->render->Show Emitter option was disabled. That's the reason why I couldn't see surface but can see the grass.[image]

Comment: Oh, good you found it. I didn't think of that option.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I didn't think it'll take so much time for me to find so obvious reason)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the solution - but I suggest you check again if there are objects set to *Disable in Renders* (camera symbol in *Outliner*).

[image: camera symbol]

Because the green lawn surface seems to be above the brown surface, as a simple comparison between the preview and the render shows. I pick a certain "stone" and count the rows below - then there is more of the brick wall visible above the brown surface than above the green surface:

[image: brick wall]

Either the green surface is disabled in render or there is some information we don't have, like maybe a *Displacement* modifier on the green surface only enabled for rendering, which might move it down depending on *Midlevel* setting for example.

Comment: I tried to disable/enable camera symbol in Outliner - surface is still brown, but the grass is disappearing when disable, so I can't see the surface, not the object. Tried to disconnect all nodes from material output in shading - same result (brown surface). I'll upload blend file - hope it'll help.